# Binary for gcc 4.8 on Scientific Linux 6.1

Tags: linux, gcc, binaryfiles

I am working on a machine with Scientific Linux 6.1 for which I do not have root access, and one of the program I need to run requires a particular library version that is contained in gcc from version 4.8.1 on.

Unfortunately the last version installed on the system is 4.7.2, so I was looking for some binaries in order to compile it myself in a local folder. My search for binaries was not successful and the main suggestion I have found googling was to install the devtoolset, that I can't install as I do not have root access.

Can someone point me to a place where I can find binaries?